# Passport + Node - req.isAuthentiated is not a function at Object.isLoggedIn

Tags: node.js, express, passport.js, passport-local

I've got an error with my code, with a passport function.

I followed this tutorial: [Sample tutorial followed](https://scotch.io/tutorials/easy-node-authentication-setup-and-local)

And I get an error from /routes file in nodemon server.js:

> TypeError: req.isAuthentiated is not a function

And this error in the browser window when I attempt to login (I can sign up, and the db is storing users):

```
TypeError: req.isAuthentiated is not a function at Object.isLoggedIn [as handle]
```

This is a passport function and I'm confused on how to remedy this.

server.js:

```
var express  = require('express');
var app      = express();
var port     = process.env.PORT || 8080;
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var passport = require('passport');
var flash    = require('connect-flash'); // messages stored in session 

var morgan       = require('morgan');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var bodyParser   = require('body-parser');
var session      = require('express-session');

var configDB = require('./config/database.js');

// configuration 
mongoose.connect(configDB.url); // connect to our database

require('./config/passport')(passport); // pass passport for configuration

// set up our express application
app.use(morgan('dev')); // log every request to the console
app.use(cookieParser()); // read cookies (needed for auth)
app.use(bodyParser.json()); // get information from html forms
    app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended : true})); // for express 4
app.set('view engine', 'ejs'); // set up ejs for templating

// required for passport
app.use(session({ secret: 'ilovescotchscotchyscotchscotch' })); // session secret
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session()); // persistent login sessions
app.use(flash()); // use connect-flash for flash messages stored in session

// routes 
require('./models/routes.js')(app, passport); 
// load our routes and  pass in our app and fully configured passport

// launch      
app.listen(port);
console.log('The magic happens on port ' + port);
```

routes.js

```
    var flash = require('connect-flash');
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

//module.exports = function (app, passport){
module.exports = function (app, passport){
    // get homepage
    app.get('/', function(req, res){
        res.render('index.ejs');
    });
    // show login form
    app.get('/login', function(req, res){
        // render page and pass in any flash data i(f there is any)
        res.render('login.ejs', {message: req.flash('loginMessage') });
    });

    // process login form
    app.get('/signup', function(req, res) {
        //render page, pass in any flash data (if there is any)
        res.render('signup.ejs', {message: req.flash('signupMessage') });
    });

    // process signup form
    // app.post('/signup', do all passport stuff here);

    // PROFILE SECTION
    // route to middleware to verify this (w/ isLoggedIn fn)
    app.get('/profile', isLoggedIn, function(req, res) {
        res.render('profile.ejs', {
            user: req.user //get user out of session pass to template
        });
    });

    // LOG OUT
    app.get('/logout', function(req, res) {
        req.logout(); // provided by passport
        res.redirect('/');
    });

      // process the signup form
    app.post('/signup', passport.authenticate('local-signup', {
        successRedirect : '/profile', // redirect to the secure profile section
        failureRedirect : '/signup', // redirect back to the signup page if there is an error
        failureFlash : true // allow flash messages
    }));

    // process the login form
    app.post('/login', passport.authenticate('local-login', {
        successRedirect : '/profile', // redirect to the secure profile section
        failureRedirect : '/login', // redirect back to the signup page if there is an error
        failureFlash : true // allow flash messages
    }));

 return router;
};


// route to middleware to make sure user is logged in
function isLoggedIn(req, res, next) {

    // if user is logged in - 
    if (req.isAuthentiated())
        return next();

    // if they aren't redirect them to home
    res.redirect('/');
}
```

Comment: Have you tried `req.user.authenticated` instead of `req.isAuthenticated()`?

Comment: isAuthenticated? minor typo?

Comment: The tutorial this is taken from uses express 3.0. Maybe `isAuthenticated()` has been removed in 4.0?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
function isLoggedIn(req, res, next) {
    if (req.isAuthenticated())  // <-- typo here
        return next();
    res.redirect('/');
}
```

Comment: Thank you, that was it!! Always pays to have a fresh set of eyes. I can't tell you how long I've spent on this.

Comment: No problem. Here to help.